# Is it fine to design a table with three foreign keys of other tables only?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have three tables in MySql: user, role and project. The relationship is one user can join many projects and one user can have different roles for different projects.

So it's like:

User, user_A, can be a role, manager in project project_A;
User, user_A, can be a role, participant in project project_B;
User, user_B, can be a role, manager in project project_B;

I have the user table:

User table:

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| user  | user_id    | user_name  |
+-------+------------+------------+
|       | 1          | Tom        |
|       | 2          | Bill       |
|       | 3          | Anna       |
|       | 4          | Mary       |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

Role table:

```
+-------+------------+-------------+
| role  | role_id    | role_name   |
+-------+------------+-------------+
|       | 1          | manager     |
|       | 2          | participant |
+-------+------------+-------------+
```

Project table:

```
+---------+------------+--------------+
| project | project_id | project_name |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|         | 1          | project_A    |
|         | 2          | project_B    |
|         | 3          | project_C    |
+---------+------------+--------------+
```

Can I have a conjection table to save the relationship with user, role and project? like the below,

```
+-------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| user_project_role | project_id | user_id | role_id |
+-------------------+------------+---------+---------+
|                   | 1          | 1       | 1       |
|                   | 1          | 2       | 2       |
|                   | 2          | 2       | 1       |
|                   | 2          | 1       | 2       |
|                   | 2          | 3       | 2       |
|                   | 3          | 1       | 2       |
|                   | 3          | 2       | 2       |
|                   | 3          | 3       | 2       |
|                   | 3          | 4       | 1       |
+-------------------+------------+---------+---------+
```

If this is not correct, how should I change this?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I have a conjection table to save the relationship with user, role and project?

Yes, you can.

> If this is not correct, how should I change this?

We cannot tell, we have no enough info.

For example, if any role which is present in `roles` table may be applied to any project in `projects` table than the scheme may be correct.

But if the project have only definite roles list (for example, `project1` may have `admin`, `user` and `guest` roles whereas `project2` may have `admin`, `manager` and `user` roles) then the scheme is not correct. You must have junction table `project_to_role` between `projects` and `roles`, and junction table `assigned_roles` between `users` and `project_to_role`.

Comment: Can a junction table, like project_to_role here, has an ID column to create another junction table?

Comment: Of course. Synthetic AI PK is preferred option, especially when project-to-role may be cosidered to be an entity.

Answer (score 0):

> The relationship is one user can join many projects and one user can have different roles for different projects.

Not enough information to say for certain.

If a User can only be "involved" with a Project by virtue of holding a specific Role within that Project, then you probably need another table defining the Roles within each Project.

```
select * from projects ; 

+----+-----------------+ 
| id | name            | 
+----+-----------------+ 
|  1 | Simple Project  | 
|  2 | Complex Project | 
+----+-----------------+ 

select * from project_roles ; 

+----+------------+-----------+ 
| id | project_id | name      | 
+----+------------+-----------+ 
| 22 |          1 | Manager   | 
| 33 |          1 | Worker    | 
| 44 |          2 | Manager   | 
| 55 |          2 | Assistant | 
| 66 |          2 | Worker    | 
| 77 |          2 | Cleaner   | 
+----+------------+-----------+ 

select * from user_project_roles ; 

+---------+------------+ 
| user_id | prj_rol_id | 
+---------+------------+ 
|     333 |         22 | 
+---------+------------+
```

This allows a User to work on multiple Projects at the same time, which you also didn't mention, but I would strongly suspect you'll need.

Comment: Yes, a user is recorded on multiple projects and this user can have different role on those multiple projects. This is what I want to have. Another thing, I'm confused why the information is not enough, what's the difference for different scenarios? Sorry, my bad, I cannot realize the difference.

Comment: Questions, questions, questions: 
Does the relationship between user and project matter independently of roles? (Answered: No)
Do all projects have the /same/ roles?  
Can a User work on more than one project at a time? (Answered: Yes).  
Can a Project Role exist independently of anyone holding that Role? (needs its own table)
Keep questioning your table structures.  DO NOT be tempted to stop with the first solution you come up with.  Try it out and make sure it holds water - or your data, at any rate ;-).